# Extract all the regex matches of a webpage with casperjs ( emails )

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, automation, casperjs, headless-browser

i would like to get all the emails from a list of urls using casperjs and this js function that gets all the emails from a page :

```js
var emailList = [];
var urlList= ["http://fr-fr.facebook.com/","http://twitter.com/","https://www.google.fr/"]
function getEmails() {

var search_in = document.body.innerHTML;
string_context = search_in.toString();

array_mails = string_context.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);
emailList.push(array_mails);

}
for(var i=0;i < urlList.length;i++){
window.location = urlList[i];
getEmails();
}
console.log(emailList);
```

Thank you so much